# How to enumerate a range of numbers starting at 1

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.5, I want an enumeration like so (starting at 1 instead of 0):

```
[(1, 2000), (2, 2001), (3, 2002), (4, 2003), (5, 2004)]
```

I know in Python 2.6 you can do: h = enumerate(range(2000, 2005), 1) to give the above result but in python2.5 you cannot...

Using Python 2.5:

```
>>> h = enumerate(range(2000, 2005))
>>> [x for x in h]
[(0, 2000), (1, 2001), (2, 2002), (3, 2003), (4, 2004)]
```

Does anyone know a way to get that desired result in Python 2.5?

Comment: Just curious, as I'm someone who hasn't done much in the way of Python professionally.  Are you limited to Python 2.5 because your company doesn't want to make the upgrade for compatibility reasons?

Comment: All 2.x version are backwards compatible, so that is no reason.

Comment: Tell that to some modules - there are a few out there that work in Py 2.5 but not Py 2.6

Answer (score 244, accepted):

As you already mentioned, this is straightforward to do in Python 2.6 or newer:

```
enumerate(range(2000, 2005), 1)
```

Python 2.5 and older do not support the `start` parameter so instead you could create two range objects and zip them:

```
r = xrange(2000, 2005)
r2 = xrange(1, len(r) + 1)
h = zip(r2, r)
print h
```

Result:

```
[(1, 2000), (2, 2001), (3, 2002), (4, 2003), (5, 2004)]
```

If you want to create a generator instead of a list then you can use [izip](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead.

Comment: using `izip` and `xrange` would be closer to enumerate

Comment: This answer is way out of date, you can now put just `enumerate(iterable, start=1)` as of Python 2.6.

Comment: @frb: Did you read the question? He already knows the solution for Python 2.6. He specifically asked for a solution that works in Python 2.5.

Comment: @MarkByers Apparently I'm blind :) Really sorry about that. (This is #1 in Google for "enumerate starting at 1")

Comment: @8chan yep, i just got here from google searching "does enumerate start from zero python" :)

Answer (score 197):

Just to put this here for posterity sake, in 2.6 the "start" parameter was added to enumerate like so:

`enumerate(sequence, start=1)`

Comment: Note that this doesn't skip the first item in the list, it offsets the index by the start value, so you would get an array out of bounds if you did something like: `sequence[i]` in your code.

Comment: This is still the same as `enumerate(sequence, 1)` but it's better to be explicit as it identifies clearly the meaning of the parameter without relying on memory of the parameter order.

Answer (score 43):

## Python 3

**Official Python documentation:** [`enumerate(iterable, start=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate)

You don't need to write your own **generator** as other answers here suggest. The built-in *Python standard library* already contains a function that does exactly what you want:

```py
>>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
>>> list(enumerate(seasons))
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
>>> list(enumerate(seasons, start=1))
[(1, 'Spring'), (2, 'Summer'), (3, 'Fall'), (4, 'Winter')]
```

---

The built-in function is equivalent to this:

```py
def enumerate(sequence, start=0):
  n = start
  for elem in sequence:
    yield n, elem
    n += 1
```

Answer (score 14):

Easy, just define your own function that does what you want:

```
def enum(seq, start=0):
    for i, x in enumerate(seq):
        yield i+start, x
```

Answer (score 10):

Simplest way to do in Python 2.5 exactly what you ask about:

```
import itertools as it

... it.izip(it.count(1), xrange(2000, 2005)) ...
```

If you want a list, as you appear to, use `zip` in lieu of `it.izip`.

(BTW, as a general rule, the best way to make a list out of a generator or any other iterable X is *not* `[x for x in X]`, but rather `list(X)`).

Answer (score 6):

```
from itertools import count, izip

def enumerate(L, n=0):
    return izip( count(n), L)

# if 2.5 has no count
def count(n=0):
    while True:
        yield n
        n+=1
```

Now `h = list(enumerate(xrange(2000, 2005), 1))` works.

Answer (score 6):

enumerate is trivial, and so is re-implementing it to accept a start:

```
def enumerate(iterable, start = 0):
    n = start
    for i in iterable:
        yield n, i
        n += 1
```

Note that this doesn't break code using enumerate without start argument. <s>Alternatively, this oneliner may be more elegant and possibly faster, but breaks other uses of enumerate:</s>

```
enumerate = ((index+1, item) for index, item)
```

The latter was pure nonsense. @Duncan got the wrapper right.

Comment: Yep, total nonsense. Something along these lines would actually work in e.g. Haskell (currying is the most natural thing ever in that language, and due to its laziness, a function taking a list is very similar to a generator expressiong). But that doesn't excuse me - long-time python user - writing BS. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> list(enumerate(range(1999, 2005)))[1:]
[(1, 2000), (2, 2001), (3, 2002), (4, 2003), (5, 2004)]
```

Comment: enumerate should be a generator. creating a whole list at once just to iterate over if often not acceptable

Comment: Generalized:

start=4
list(enumerate(range(start)+range(1999, 2005)))[start:]

Comment: range is however list in 2.52

Answer (score 3):

`h = [(i + 1, x) for i, x in enumerate(xrange(2000, 2005))]`

Comment: He can't do this in Python 2.5. The start parameter was introduced in Python 2.6: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate. He also mentions this in the question.

Comment: Answered this before the initial edit, when the code was unformatted and the trouble seemed to me to be the use of a generator instead of a list.

Comment: `++`: that's the way to do it

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I feel a bit stupid here... what's the reason not to just do it with something like 
`[(a+1,b) for (a,b) in enumerate(r)]` ? If you won't function, no problem either:

```
>>> r = range(2000, 2005)
>>> [(a+1,b) for (a,b) in enumerate(r)]
[(1, 2000), (2, 2001), (3, 2002), (4, 2003), (5, 2004)]

>>> enumerate1 = lambda r:((a+1,b) for (a,b) in enumerate(r)) 

>>> list(enumerate1(range(2000,2005)))   # note - generator just like original enumerate()
[(1, 2000), (2, 2001), (3, 2002), (4, 2003), (5, 2004)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> h = enumerate(range(2000, 2005))
>>> [(tup[0]+1, tup[1]) for tup in h]
[(1, 2000), (2, 2001), (3, 2002), (4, 2003), (5, 2004)]
```

Since this is somewhat verbose, I'd recommend writing your own function to generalize it:

```
def enumerate_at(xs, start):
    return ((tup[0]+start, tup[1]) for tup in enumerate(xs))
```

Comment: enumerate should be a generator. creating a whole list at once just to iterate over if often not acceptable

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how these posts could possibly be made more complicated then the following:

```
# Just pass the start argument to enumerate ...
for i,word in enumerate(allWords, 1):
    word2idx[word]=i
    idx2word[i]=word
```