# python: dictionary comprehension with list index

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'd like to create dictionary with a key containing the indexed position of a value in a list. I'm using python 2.7. Consider my attempt:

```
LL = ["this","is","a","sample","list"]
LL_lookup = {LL.index(l):l for (LL.index(l), l) in LL}

# desired output
print LL_lookup[1]
>> is
```

I recognize that a dictionary isn't necessary in this example- `LL[1]` would yield the same result. Nonetheless, we can imagine a circumstance where 1) a dictionary is preferable given a more complex example, and b) a dictionary look up may yield marginal performance gains with a large number of iterations.

Comment: Note `.index` is not reliable, it returns the first index of an item so won't work properly for duplicate elements

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> LL = ["this","is","a","sample","list"]
>>> dict(enumerate(LL))
{0: 'this', 1: 'is', 2: 'a', 3: 'sample', 4: 'list'}
```

Comment: Beautiful. Python at it's best!
Also, can start enumeration at specific value like suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3303640/929164)

Answer (score 5):

```
inp = ["this","is","a","sample","list"]

print {idx: value for idx, value in enumerate(inp)}
```