# Python -- how to force enumerate to start at 1 -- or workaround?

Tags: python, for-loop, enumeration, modulus

I have a simple for loop:

```
for index, (key, value) in enumerate(self.addArgs["khzObj"].nodes.items()):
```

and I want to start a new wx horizontal boxsizer after every 3rd item to create a panel with 3 nodes each and going on for as many as are in nodes.  The obvious solution is to do:

```
if index % 3 == 0: add a horizontal spacer
```

but the enumerate starts at 0, so 0 % 3 == 0 and it would start a new row right off the bat.  I've tried doing:

```
if index == 0: index = index + 1
```

but of course that doesn't work because it creates a new var instead of changing the original -- so I get 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc and that won't work because I'll get 4 nodes before I hit a index % 3 == 0.

Any suggestions on how to do this?  This isn't a big enumerate, usually only about 10-15 items.  Thanks.

Comment: Read. The. Documentation. `pydoc enumerate` is less effort than asking here...

Comment: A similar question has already been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303608/how-to-enumerate-a-range-of-numbers-starting-at-1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since Python 2.6, `enumerate()` takes an optional `start` parameter to indicate where to start the enumeration. See [the documentation for `enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: I didn't know that, guess you learn something new every day. Good job.

Comment: Before that was added, `itertools.izip(itertools.count(1), L)` would have been the way to do it.

Comment: `＋1` This is actually pretty handy to know, but the op could also just use `index % 3 == 2`

Comment: Using enumerate will still loop through all of the elements, it just changes which position it starts at.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to hate this answer for how obvious it is, but you could just do:

```
if index % 3 == 2: add a horizontal spacer
```

This adds the spacer after the 2nd element (which is actually the third), and every third element after it.

Comment: I didn't notice that -- fancy.  I marked Daniel's as correct, though, because it's a bit more explicit and it helps me in other situations that aren't so neat and tidy ;)

Comment: His solution is certainly nifty.