# How to print every item in a list with its No. before it in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist

For example, I have a list of names: ["joe","ben","alex"]
How can I print like this:

`1. joe
2. ben
3. alex`

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enumerate a range of numbers starting at 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303608/how-to-enumerate-a-range-of-numbers-starting-at-1)

Comment: I guess your homework has been answered, still I believe a downvote is in order due to lack of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate might be what you're looking for.  For further reading about it you can check out http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html

with your data, you can do something like

```
my_list = ["joe","ben","alex"]
for c, value in enumerate(my_list, 1):
    print(c, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in function **enumerate** like so:

```
mylist = ["joe","ben","alex"]
for indx, val in enumerate (mylist):
    print (str(indx +1) +"." , val)
```