# How to give serial numbers before my output strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a python script to get the name of Wikimedia contributors in a CSV output file as follows;-

velu

ramu

ஆதி

How can i give serial numbers to those names? Like below;-

1.velu

2.ramu

3.ஆதி

My code: It reads a file and removes duplicates. Finally, i want to give serial numbers.

```
content = open('contributors.csv','r').readlines()
content4set = set(content)
cleanedcontent = open('contributors-cleaned.csv','w')
for line in content4set:
    cleanedcontent.write(line.replace('பக்கம்','அட்டவணை_பேச்சு'))
    line=line.strip()
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can.

```
content = open('contributors.csv','r').readlines()
content4set = set(content)
cleanedcontent = open('contributors-cleaned.csv','w')
for i, line in enumerate(content4set):
    cleanedcontent.write("{}.{}".format(str(i+1),line.replace('பக்கம்','அட்டவணை_பேச்சு')))
    line=line.strip()
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index along with each line. `i` is the index of the line. Note that you'll need Python 3.6 or newer as this code uses formatted strings.

```
content = open('contributors.csv','r').readlines()
content4set = set(content)
cleanedcontent = open('contributors-cleaned.csv','w')
for i, line in enumerate(content4set):
    line = line.strip().replace('பக்கம்','அட்டவணை_பேச்சு')
    line = f"{i+1}. {line}"
    print(line, file = cleanedcontent)
    print(line)
```

Comment: @Ramachandra Apte works fine in python 3.5.2 but the serial number not appearing in terminal. But prints in the document. Why?

Comment: @info-farmer I've changed my code to print the serial number in the terminal.

Comment: @Ramachandra Apte Due to line 6, error "invalid syntex" appears

Answer (score 0):

I learned from both your approaches and rearranged with [another article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303608/how-to-enumerate-a-range-of-numbers-starting-at-1) as follows;-

```
content = open('contributors.csv','r').readlines()
content4set = set(content)
cleanedcontent = open('contributors-cleaned.csv','w')
for i, line in enumerate(content4set,1):
    cleanedcontent.write("{}.{}".format(str(i+1),line.replace('பக்கம்','அட்டவணை_பேச்சு')))
    line=line.strip()
    print(i, line)
```

My output result is,

1 velu

2 ramu

3 ஆதி

Thanks indeed both of you.