# How to enumerate dictionary keys not from 0 but from 1? In the example below

Tags: python

Input:

```
keys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(dict(enumerate([i ** 2 for i in keys])))
```

Output:

```
{0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 9, 3: 16, 4: 25, 5: 36, 6: 49, 7: 64, 8: 81, 9: 100}
```

But need to make:

```
{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81, 10: 100}
```

Many thanks to anyone who read it for your time and everyone for advice!

Comment: `print(dict(enumerate([i ** 2 for i in keys], start=1)))`

Comment: Why do you need a dictionnary instead of a list ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enumerate a range of numbers starting at 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303608/how-to-enumerate-a-range-of-numbers-starting-at-1)

Answer (score 2):

Please google your question before asking it
It's already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3303640/11805525)

```py
>>> keys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> print(dict(enumerate([i ** 2 for i in keys], 1)))
{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81, 10: 100}
```

If you are using an IDE, You can just hold `CTRL` and click on the function `enumerate`. It will show the source of python and I'm sure you'll find your asnwer realy fast

```py
# builtins.py
def __init__(self, iterable, start=0): # known special case of enumerate.__init__
    """ Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature. """
    pass
```

Comment: The problem the in the reference you gave (which I actually saw before) there is example for List but I need to make it in Dictionary. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @StanislavVoloshchuk The type of output doesn't matter because you are casting it to the output. It's the enumerate function's behavior. I edited my answer; Take a look at the source.