# how to enumerate list but start index from 1?

Tags: python, enumerate

```
d = [37,12,28,9,100,56,80,5,12]

list(enumerate(d))
```

will give:

```
[(0, 37), (1, 12), (2, 28), (3, 9), (4, 100), (5, 56), (6, 80), (7, 5), (8, 12)]
```

But i want index to start from 1, how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enumerate a range of numbers starting at 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303608/how-to-enumerate-a-range-of-numbers-starting-at-1)

Comment: A first good place to look is the [`enumerate()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Already from the signature you will get yor answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
list(enumerate(d, start=1))
```

output:

```
[(1, 37),
 (2, 12),
 (3, 28),
 (4, 9),
 (5, 100),
 (6, 56),
 (7, 80),
 (8, 5),
 (9, 12)]
```